# iOS remote build fails in Visual Studio TACO

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I develop cordova app with Visual Studio 2015 in Windows7.

Node version on Mac is v5.1.0.

While running remotebuild on Mac, start building from Visual Studio.

In emulator mode, it seems to build correctly (msk.test.build.app is created in 'platforms/ios/build/emulator'.)

In device mode, build fails with error below.

I found 'platforms/ios/build/device' is not created, but don't know how to fix.

```
Submitting new build request to: https://Macintosh.local:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.4.0&cfg=debug&options=--device&buildNumber=1403&loglevel=warn
------ new build: {"command":"build","vcordova":"5.4.0","cfg":"debug","options":"--device","buildNumber":"1403","loglevel":"warn","status":"Uploaded","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildLang":"ja-JP","buildDir":"/Users/User/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1403","logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2015-11-18T21:38:43.650Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageArgs":null,"message":"Uploaded build request payload.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/User/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1403/upload_1403.tgz","appDir":"/Users/User/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1403/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2015-11-18T21:38:43.652Z"}

  error - Build failed with error Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun -v -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication platforms/ios/build/device/msk.test.build.app -o /Users/User/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1403/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/BuildTest2.ipa
  xcrun: note: PATH = '/Users/User/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/1.2.0/node_modules/taco-remote-lib/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:”/Applications/Adobe'
  xcrun: note: SDKROOT = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk'
  xcrun: note: TOOLCHAINS = ''
  xcrun: note: DEVELOPER_DIR = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'
  xcrun: note: XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH = ''
  xcrun: note: xcrun_db = '/var/folders/_4/x16l03kx0mxbgd6w_5zp0y5w0000gn/T/xcrun_db'
  xcrun: note: xcrun via PackageApplication (xcrun)
  xcrun: note: database key is: PackageApplication|/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk||/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer|
  xcrun: note: lookup resolved in '/var/folders/_4/x16l03kx0mxbgd6w_5zp0y5w0000gn/T/xcrun_db' : '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication'
MDAVSCLI : error : Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/msk.test.build.app'
```

### -------------------------------------

I tried node@0.12.7 on Mac, it works better thanks!

Building works fine and .ipa is created both on Windows/Mac, but stops installing app to my iphone connected by USB to Windows.

Visual Studio output console shows below( the words may be different because mine is Japanese).

```
 :
 :
1>  ------ copying to project: iOS
2>------ start configuration: project: MSK App, composition:Debug iOS ------
```

Comment: What version of node do you have installed on the Mac?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Node version is v5.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is a compatibility issue between your version of Node and Cordova 5.4. We are working on fixes both to remote build and Visual Studio to address some of these, but in the meantime I suggest you downgrade to Cordova 5.3 and also take an earlier version of Node (4.2.2 should be OK). That should fix the issue.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I downgraded to cordova 4.3 on Windows because of other programmatic reason.
Downgraded to node 4.2.2 on Mac, I met other issue  like this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10454 .
So I end up upgrading to node 5.1.0 again and build ios without remotebuild.

Comment: The only version of node that works with remote build and Cordova 4.3 is 0.12.7. Can you try that?

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with Node version > 4 and Cordova <= 5.3.3  that have been documented [here](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/known-issues-general/). Also we are seeing issues with Cordova 5.4 and are recommending to downgrade as Michael suggests.

Look Specifically at -

- Build not executing when using Cordova with Node.js 5.0.0+ and Cordova 5.3.3 and below
- Build hangs or does not execute when building for iOS with Cordova < 5.3.3 and Node.js 4.0.0+

Subhag Oak
(Microsoft)